# How do I set up a system SDK in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

I'm trying to add a Java SDK installed on my system to a project in Intellij Idea Community 2021.2 on Pop_OS! linux. The SDK is located at `/usr/lib/jvm/`. When opening the dialogue to select an SDK the dialogue the `/usr/lib/` directory does not match that on my system and does not include the `jvm` directory.
I've opened the dialogue as follows `File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings / SDKs -> + -> Add JDK...`

The dialogue

[image: /usr/lib in select Java SDK directory dialogue]

The `/usr/lib/` directory when listed in the terminal

[image: Contents of /usr/lib/ directory from terminal]

[image: Details of /usr/lib/jvm directory from terminal]

This feels like a weird permissions issue, but I'm at a loss. I know there are other ways to add an SDK, but this happens for all dialogues where I need to select something from the file system so I'd like to get a fix for this.

**Update:** I originally posted shots for the `/usr/` directory rather than `/usr/lib/`, although both are showing similar issues. Original screen shots are below

The dialogue

[image: Select Java SDK directory dialogue]

The `usr` directory when listed in the terminal

[image: Contents of /usr/ directory from terminal]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html

Comment: from your screen shot it's on your 6th sub folder of the usr directory and from your terminal screen shoot it has read permission for other users which will make the ide able to read it 

so not sure what is the issue 

did you get certain error when you do so 

also try this in terminal java --version what is the output?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the /usr/ and /usr/lib directories. I've clarified in the question, although the issue is happening to both directories.

Comment: Have you tried to download JDK achieve, expand and select it as SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely installed IntelliJ as a flatpack. Since the application is in a sandbox some directories are not accessible or overridden (see [official docs](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html))